# SerializationException when making Gettem request to DynamoDB via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm making a GetItem call to a DynamoDB via API Gateway integration. My request mapping is:

`{
   "TableName": "connected-content-dynamodb",
   "Key": {
      { "id" :
        {"S" : "$input.params('entity-id')"}
      }
   }
}`

Response template is:
`{ "payload" : "$input.json('$')"}`

Logs that I get:

Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
   "TableName": "connected-content-dynamodb",
   "Key": {
      { "id" :
        {"S" : "123"}
      }
   }
}

Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Sending request to https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetItem
Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Method response body after transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5bf68597-8d22f7ca52c6af2aded083e0, Content-Type=application/json}
Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Successfully completed execution
Thu Nov 22 10:31:51 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 404

Any ideas whats wrong? Or how to debug it?

Comment: This is entirely speculation, but it looks like you have extra `{` and `}` in your request json. Maybe that’s the problem. It definitely possible that it could cause a com.amazon.coral.SerializationException.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sadly no. we've stuck to using Query for now. It works except we always get 200 response code even when there is no result. But tbh only discovered logging afterwards.

Comment: Per the 200 response - look into Method Response or Integration Response of your API Gateway Service Resource.  I think you may be able to customize the Response and/or mapping there.